# Replacing redundant keys and values in a dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary

Is there an elegant way to go through a dictionary and if there are identical keys and values, remove them and connect the leftovers to a new key-value pair?

e.g.

```
d = {Olomouc: Bratislava, Brno: Jihlava, Znojmo: Olomouc, Opole: Liberec, Trnava: Prague}
```

desired output (`Olomouc` removed and `Znojmo:Bratislava` pair created):

```
d = {Znojmo: Bratislava, Brno: Jihlava, Opole: Liberec, Trnava: Prague}
```

Comment: imagine  `d = {'a':'b','b':'c','c':'a'}`                            What output do you want ?

Comment: Imagine `d = {'a':'c', 'b':'c', 'c':'x'}` . What output do you want?

Comment: Please provide an algorithm for the replacements, as well as what you have done.

Comment: rambi:  the outcome would be an empty dictionary (which is not a problem)

Comment: Jim DeLaHunt : I have forgotten to mention that the dictionary is created as a part of a more complex algorithm, and so the case you provided, would not really occur in my code (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c2ft8AG8JKE)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using inverse dictionary:

```
inv_d = {v: k for k, v in d.items()}
for v in inv_d:
    if v in d:
       d.pop(inv_d[v])
       d[inv_d[v]] = d[v]
       d.pop(v)
```